# Dynamically creating a photo gallery with coldfusion

Tags: html, image, coldfusion

I have folder filled with at least 100 images that I want to display in a gallery using coldfusion. I was able to loop the directory and get the absolute paths of the images in the image folder. But I am having trouble passing in the absolute paths into the html img tags. I even tried using cfimage tag and that failed as well. Here is my code.

```
<body>
<cfinclude template="header.cfm" >
<cfdirectory action="list" directory="C:\ColdFusion2016\cfusion\wwwroot\project\img" name="listRoot">      
<cfoutput query="listRoot">
    <cfset myPath= expandpath(#listRoot.NAME#)>     
    <!---#listRoot.Name#<br>--->            
    <b>File Path : </b> #myPath# <br>
    <img src=#myPath#>
    <!---<cfimage action="info" source="#myPath#" structname="stInfo" >
    <cfdump var="#stInfo#" label="Photo Info">--->
</cfoutput>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you describe what's not working? Is `myPath` incorrect?

Answer (score 2):

Why do you want the file system path? Just output the filename and prepend the src with the directory if necessary.

```
<cfdirectory action="list" directory="C:\ColdFusion2016\cfusion\wwwroot\project\img" name="listRoot">      
<cfoutput query="listRoot">
  <img src="/project/img/#name#">
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: Thank you. I think I was just making things more complicated then they needed to be. I thought that I needed to have the absolute path to retrieve the image. Thanks again.

Comment: @user3426338 - It can be absolute, but should be a url, rather than a physical file path ie ie `/` (web root) instead of C:\ColdFusion2016\cfusion\wwwroot\ . That said, a physical file path should work fine with `<cfimage>`. Tip: When a physical path is not working as expected, display it on screen and *also* use functions like FileExists() or DirectoryExists() to verify you really have the correct path value.

Comment: And once you have that patch, you can also use something like photoswipe (photoswipe.com) and pass that the location of all of your images. It is able to then create a very nice photo gallery for you based on the images that you pass the locations too.